# Is it right to say "you wanna join?" to invite someone to join me for the activity

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english, transitivity, colloquial-language

Is it right to say "you wanna join?" to invite someone to join me for the activity? Is it causal English or not grammatical at all. thanks. I know it's correct to say "you wanna join me?", however i wonder if "you wanna join" works as well here. Thank you

Comment: Note that **causal** is the wrong word. Try **casual**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You wanna join [me]?* is a very informal (or casual, if that is what you mean) way of asking *Do you want to join [me]?* It is neither correct nor grammatical, but it is idiomatic as a representation of informal speech.

If you leave out the *me* it means *Do you want to join [the activity]?*

Comment: perfect thanks it's weird that i searched about "do you wanna join" on ludwig and youglish  but only few results show up, thought i was wrong. so, do people use "you wanna join" often in everyday english?

Comment: People younger than I am may do! To me, _D'you want to join [the group or activity]?_ or _Would you like to join?_ would be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

The word **[join](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/join)** can mean DO TOGETHER or BECOME A MEMBER. If you want to use the DO TOGETHER meaning, it requires an object, for example **join me** or **join us**, or a preposition **join with...**.

The BECOME A MEMBER meaning can be used without an object, as long as it's clear what group or organization somebody became a member of:

> It's a great club. Why don't you join?

I would therefore assume that "You wanna join?" was asking whether I wanted to become a member of some club or organization.

Another option to consider is **[join in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/join-in)**. You would use that if you are part of a group of people doing something, and wish to invite another person to participate.